# php str_getcsv remove from array null or ' ' values

Tags: php, laravel, csv

i have a piece of code here in php which accepts a csv file and return it back to view to the user. problem is there are row with empty value. i want it to be not included in the array if the loop finds it null or empty. i want to remove row from array if [6] is empty

```
public function import_csv(Request $request){

    $fileName = $request->coins_csv;

    $csvData = file_get_contents($fileName);
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);

    $data = array();

    foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {

        $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }

    // remove header unset($data[0]);

    dd($data);
}
```

here the csv file look like. i want to remove row from array if [6] is empty

```
1 => array:7 [▼
0 => "0c1ff12044f941aa8e383800f2ac45f8"
1 => "bills_payment_donation_sanjoseseminary"
2 => "PHP"
3 => "713.37"
4 => "2020-03-01 2:27:24"
5 => "Vincent L./ Arms of God to help you"
6 => "sanjoseseminaryendowment"
]

2 => array:7 [▼
0 => "1b2fc702f354450dbab15aa7d46d175a"
1 => "bills_payment_donation_gk"
2 => "PHP"
3 => "300"
4 => "2020-03-03 10:35:54"
5 => "chloe lloveras"
6 => ""
]
```

thank you in advance. folks

Comment: $tempData = str_getcsv($line); if($tempdata !=""){$data[]  = $tempData ;}

Comment: does not work @Grumpy

Comment: I see now, you have to loop through the str_getcsv($line) like $tmpArray = str_getcsv($line); loop through the values and remove the empty ones